# How does the U.S agriculture subsidy not constitute export subsidies under the WTO?

Tags: subsidies, international-trade

The WTO explicitly prohibits subsidies on export goods to prevent dumping and market distortion but the United States spends `$2.4` Billion annually on corn subsidies and has a trade surplus of `$19.5` billion in agricultural goods.

How does this subsidy not constitute dumping under the WTO guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain types of agricultural subsidies are permitted under the WTO's [Green Box](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/agric_e/agboxes_e.htm). These include direct income support for farmers, and environmental and regional development programmes. However the rules state that, to qualify, such subsidies must be no more than minimally trade-distorting.  Whether such subsidies (in the US and other countries) actually meet that requirement is a matter of controversy, as discussed in this [ICTSD Information Note](http://www.ictsd.org/downloads/2012/02/agricultural-subsidies-in-the-wto-green-box-ensuring-coherence-with-sustainable-development-goals.pdf) which also shows (in Figure 1) the very high Green Box proportion of US subsidies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sociology issues than WTO may solved. It is impossible to level the trade playing ground in culture, especially with the ambigous term such as "minimally trade-distorting".

E.g.

- Machinery, fertilizer mostly produce in rich nations, thus make it
  cheaper, even without subsidies.
- Corporation from rich country may take a localised diversified animal/crops genes , then charged the research outcome back on the poor country without compensation on the origin.
- Agricultural Research grants from government is also a form of subsidies. Should the research lead to a lead on overall production.
- crops gene that "borrow" from poor country that do diversified crop planting rarely compensated.

[Details of WTO agriculture agreement are available in this link](https://www.wto.org/english/thewto_e/whatis_e/tif_e/agrm3_e.htm)